# How to capture text color in an Office Document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, colors

I have a Word document with some titles of a particular blue tonality, now I want to continue the document adding some others sections that uses the same colour (color that I want to use not only in text but also in others elements according the theme).

When I try to use *more colors* feature to define a new custom color is pretty hard to match exactly the SAME tonality, so I'm wondering there is some function to capture the text color to define a new custom color that you can use for all elements you want

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two solutions off the top of my head:

1:  Select the text you want the color of, then click the "More Colors Option" as seen in your screenshot.  From there, copy down the "Red, Green, Blue" colors, that will give you an exact match on the color, even if it's a non-standard color.

You can use these three numbers to add color to any element you want, text, boxes, outlines, etc.  (see blue circles)

2:  The other option, while it only works for text, would be to use the "Format Painter", basically you select the formatting you like, then click the "Format Painter" button, then select the text you want to format.  It will copy all the formatting from one section to another.  (see red circle)

[image: Color Picker.]

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a mac or pc? If on a mac, a straightforward approach is using an app like DigitalColor Meter (comes default with Mac OS X), it'll give you the R,G,B variables over whatever you hover, you can then plug this into a custom colour.

I'm sure theres a windows equivalent, a little Googling can help you there if thats the case.

Comment: This is a good solution, but since Word has all the necessary tools, it's also an added level of complexity.  Word can return the R,G,B values without the help of additional tools.

Comment: True, I'm just a Mac fan at heart :)

Comment: @tbenz9 This only works for cases where custom color is set in Word - but not if you want to have textbox match the color of background image. You still need to use external tools to find out the exact RGB components.

Comment: Digital Color Meter isn't viable because of anti-aliasing can cause you to meter the wrong color...

Answer (score 0):

Select the text that has the color that you want.  Key [SHIFT+F10) + F.  This will take you to the Font selection window.  From here the color of the font will be shown.
[image: Select the "Font color" DropDown]
[image: From here you can see the color in the "theme color" DropDown Section or you can select "More Colors..." and you will be shown a pop-up that will have the HexCode for the color in question.]

I hope this helps.